# How to Use Hilt in Launch Screen Activity Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, splash-screen, dagger-hilt

Cannot create instance of viewmodel in launchscreen activity

This is the Manifest file

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/pasumai"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/pasumai"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.PasumaiSuperMarket"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:node="replace">

<activity
        android:name=".activity.launchscreen"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/splashscreentheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am also adding @AndroidEntryPoint in launchscreen activity

This is the ViewModel Code

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginVM @Inject constructor(val repository: NewApiRepository, val useridrepository:ImplRepository, @ApplicationContext val context: Context) : ViewModel() {

val myOtp: MutableStateFlow<Resource<LoginOtp>> = MutableStateFlow(Resource.Empty)
val myLogin: MutableStateFlow<Resource<OtpVerification>> = MutableStateFlow(Resource.Empty)
var user_id : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("")
var userid: MutableLiveData<userid> = MutableLiveData()

fun saveuserid(user:String) {
   viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
       useridrepository.saveuser(
           userid(id = user)
       )
   }
}

fun retrieveUserId() {
   viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
       useridrepository.getuser().collect{
           user_id.postValue(it.id)
       }
   }
}

fun getOtp(mobile:String) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    myOtp.value = Resource.Loading
    myOtp.value = repository.getotp(90336,"send-sms", mobile)
}

fun login(mobile:String,otp:String,friends_code:String) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    myLogin.value = Resource.Loading
    myLogin.value = repository.loginuser(90336,"user-login", mobile,otp,friends_code)
 }
}
```

This is Activity Code

```
@AndroidEntryPoint

class launchscreen : AppCompatActivity() {

private val otpvm by viewModels<LoginVM>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launchscreen)

    otpvm.retrieveUserId()

    lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        otpvm.user_id.observe(this@launchscreen) {
            if(it.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                navToSignUpActivity()
            } else {
                Utils.User_id = it
                navToMainActivity()
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For ViewModels with parameters you need to create custom ViewModelProvider.Factory to pass those values to your ViewModel. Something like this:

```
class LoginVMFactory(private val mContext:Context,private val repository:NewApiRepository, val useridrepository:ImplRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return LoginVM(repository, useridrepository, mContext) as T
    }
```

and create your ViewModel like this:

```
private val otpvm by viewModels<LoginVM> {LoginVMFactory(this, repository, useridrepository)}
```

Or just use Field injection and avoid constructor injection if you do not want additional setup classes. Something like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginVM @Inject constructor() : ViewModel(){
   @Inject val repository: NewApiRepository
   @Inject val useridrepository:ImplRepository
   @Inject @ApplicationContext val context: Context
}
```

Comment: If the instances you are passing to ViewModel as parameter is provided by a hilt @module already you can just use by Fragment.viewModels delegate and the rest is taken care of with inject constructor () on your ViewModel. with your solution, you will also need to have extra field injection (or somehow instantiate those params) wherever you create your ViewModel !

Comment: @MateoVakili author has added that he is getting this error `Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.store.pasumaisupermarket.viewmodel.login.LoginVM> has no zero argument constructor`. Default viewmodel instantiation expects no arguments. If arguments is present we have to implement ViewModel.Factory. DI helps only in instantiation of object which are defined in @Module.

Comment: Fragment ktx provides a delegate for this which has a factory that works with hilt so that there is no need for you to instantiate the args of your viewModel inside your fragment. In my current application using by Fragment.viewModels() with HiltViewModel annotation does the job for you even if you have arguments for your viewModels. it also gives additional support now for savedStateHandler and so on.

Answer (score 0):

hey you need to add following dependency.

```
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
```

and now in `LaunchScreenActivity`, you need to make following things

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class LaunchScreenActivity:AppCompatActivity(){
   private val viewModel by viewModels<LaunchScreenViewModel>()
}
```

and your `LaunchScreenViewModel` should be as following:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class LaunchScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
   /*some constructor injections*/
) : ViewModel(){
   
}
```

If you got the answer you want please accept my answer by giving green check. If I haven't got your question then give me more details in comment section of this answer. Love from India.❤️

Comment: and there is something known as `ActivityScopedViewmodel` to inject a viewModel scoped to activity from fragment, you need to write `private val viewModel by activityViewModels<LaunchScreenViewModel>()`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.store.pasumaisupermarket.viewmodel.login.LoginVM> has no zero argument constructor

Comment: can you put your activity and viewModel code in you question? i think you have some constructor variable?

Comment: i have added the viewmodel and activity code please check @Shashank Daima

Comment: I am guessing that all the `repository` and `userIdRepository` are present as hilt dependencies?

Comment: yes respository and userIdRepository are present as hilt dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are providing your repositories as follows (doesnt have to be SingletonComponent depends on your use case) :

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class CoreRepositoryModule {
     @Binds
     abstract fun bindNewApiRepository(
         newApiRepository: NewApiRepositoryImpl
     ): NewApiRepository
    
     @Binds
     abstract fun bindUserIdRepository(
         userIdRepository: ImplRepository
     ): UserIdRepository
}
```

Also, I don't see your application class with @HiltAndroidApp annotation so make sure you have the following :

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication : Application()
```

Then you can just do:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.main_activity) {
    private val viewModel: LaunchScreenViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

and for viewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
   ..... your repos 
) : ViewModel()
```

further more the reason you might be getting the has no zero argument constructor error it means that the HiltViewModelFactory doesn't have a binding for your specific viewmodel. you might be missing hilt-android-compiler so please use the following in app level gradle (use apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' for kapt on top) :

```
// Dependency Injection
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.41"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.40.5"
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0'
```